# Vertex Select G not working

Tags: vertices

i’m having troubles moving the shape of the object with *Vertex Select* and G.

I’m trying to make the shape go down like this;
[image]

But when i select the vertex and press G it only drags the lines and not the whole object.

[image]

How can i fix it? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can have a look.

Comment: you most likely have previously extruded the segment which moves as you described. Delete it (as long as the case exists). And that should be ok after that.